# Error in ext-base.js

Tags: extjs

This is my EXTJS code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
var treeLoader=new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
                dataUrl:'json.php'
                                      });
var rootNode=new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
             text:'Root'
                                       });
var tree=new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
         renderTo:'treecontainer',
         loader:treeLoader,
          root:rootNode
                               });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Tree Formation </title>
<link rel=stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />
<script src="ext-base.js"> </script>
<script src="ext-all.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="tree.js"> </script>
<title id="title">Tree Formed</title>
</body>
<div id="treecontainer" style="height:300px;width:200px;">
</div>
<html>
```

Json.php:

```
 [
      {id:'1',text:'No Children',leaf:true},
      {id:'2'.text:'Has Children',
           children:[{
                       id:'3',
                       text:'Youngster',
                       leaf:true
                     }]
      }
```

After executing the above code,it's displaying with only 'Root' as done,rest not displaying.When i click on that 'Root' Error encountered as "ACCESS IS DENIED" at LINE 7,CHAR 20287 in ext-base.js.Can u tell me what it's ....?
]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the correct path to your Json.php file, or you don't have read access.

Comment: @sdavids: I'm very new to EXTJS.don't hav much idea.can u tell me in detail ? should i need to modify that library file ext-base.js ....? can u help me ?

Comment: If you see the Root node, Ext is working correctly, although when you clicked on the node to expand it, it fires an AJAX request to go pull all of the children of that AsyncTreeNode. It looks like your service call failing, not ExtJS.

Comment: are you able to hit(access) the json.php from the browser address bar? like http://localhost/app/json.php .. does this return data properly?

Comment: @sdavids: so,now how to deal with it ?

Comment: are you able to access that resource (json.php) on the browser in normal way? http://your-application-url/json.php

Comment: @Abdel: can u tell me what's the problem.

Comment: Suggestion for you to debug if you have Firebug extension for Firefox. Open it, then find and open the Net tab. After you click the Root node you should see request to json.php there and Firebug will show you if it is successfull or not.